# Minimization of the ratio of quadratic forms with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms

I don't want to re-invent the wheel so I was wondering if anything is known about this problem
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d} \quad & \frac{x^\top A x}{x^\top B x} \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & x^\top \mathbf{1} = 1 \\
    \text{and } \quad & x \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
where both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and positive definite matrices.

Comment: @amWhy However, the answer (of the question you suggested) just gives the derivative, it does not answer this problem (minimization **with contraints** )